# Will WSASend re-send data?

Tags: c++, winsockets

I'm maintaining some code which use Windows socket to send data to TCP client.

I saw WSASend is only called once. But the wireshark captured data shows 2 duplicate tries was made when time out.

I wonder, does WSASend implement a retry in itself?

Comment: [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) itself have some retries built-in, depending on the problem.

Comment: I doubted that. I think the retry is implemented by the caller, not in CWinSocket::WSASend itself.